# Set parameters in gnuplot using C++ source code

Tags: c++, plot, gnuplot

I'm trying to plot some vectors using [gnuplot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gnuplot) from C++ source code. I already read a question about how to interface C++ with the gnuplot.

This is the source code:

```
int main()
{
    char * commandsForGnuplot[] = {"set title \"Trajectory_ARM\"","plot 'data.temp' with linespoints"};
    double xvals[NUM_POINTS] = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0};
    double yvals[NUM_POINTS] = {5.0 ,3.0, 1.0, 3.0, 5.0};
    FILE * temp = fopen("data.temp", "w");

    /*Opens an interface that one can use to send commands as if they were typing into the
     *     gnuplot command line.  "The -persistent" keeps the plot open even after your
     *     C program terminates.
     */
    FILE * gnuplotPipe = popen ("gnuplot -persistent", "w");
    int i;
    for (i=0; i < NUM_POINTS; i++)
    {
        fprintf(temp, "%lf %lf \n", xvals[i]  , yvals[i]); //Write the data to a temporary file
    }

    for (i=0; i < NUM_COMMANDS; i++)
    {
        fprintf(gnuplotPipe, "%s \n", commandsForGnuplot[i]); //Send commands to gnuplot one by one.
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is:

I have a new vector of 5 points(A) and I want to have in the same plot A and xvals in respect of yvals. How should I modify my code? In this case I would like to plot A and xvals with two different colors.

Comment: My answer to the same question(s) on c.g.a.gnuplot applies: Find out if this is a problem with your gnuplot commands by putting them in an ordinary gnuplot script!

Answer (score 0):

This is a complete source code formatted in C. I have just added a third vector `A`, and a third instruction to `commandsForGnuplot` (`'' u 1:3 w lp`) which plots this vector `A` with respect to `xvals`.  Notice that gnuplot draws each line with different colors by default.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NUM_POINTS   5    // each vector has 5 points

int main()
{
  double xvals[NUM_POINTS] = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0};
  double yvals[NUM_POINTS] = {5.0 ,3.0, 1.0, 3.0, 5.0};
  double Avals[NUM_POINTS] = {4.0 ,5.0, 3.0, 0.0, 1.0};

  int i;
  //Write xvals, yvals, and Avals to a temporary file              
  FILE * temp = fopen("data.temp", "w");

  for(i=0; i < NUM_POINTS; i++)
    fprintf(temp, "%lf %lf %lf\n", xvals[i]  , yvals[i], Avals[i]);

  fclose(temp);   // close file if it won't be used anymore

  // open interface to gnuplot. Option -p lets plot windows survive after program exits
  FILE * gnuplotPipe = popen ("gnuplot -p", "w");

  // send commands to gnuplot one by one.
  fprintf(gnuplotPipe, "%s \n", "set title 'Trajectory\\_ARM'");      // command 0: define the graph title
  fprintf(gnuplotPipe, "%s \n", "plot 'data.temp' u 1:2 w lp");       // command 1: plot yvals vs xvals, and Avals vs xvals

  fflush(gnuplotPipe);      // plots the data with the current commands

  // we obtained a plot of data.temp
  // now, we place an instruction to pause the program until a key is typed
  getchar();                

  // add a plot to the current graph
  fprintf(gnuplotPipe, "%s \n", "replot 'data.temp' u 1:3 w lp");

  pclose(gnuplotPipe);      // close gnuplot if it won't be used anymore
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: perfect,but in this way i have the plot when the esecution of the program is finished.
If i want to have it immediately??
For example if i put an inifinite loop before the return 0 a will not have the plot

Comment: The thing is that `popen` is used to pipe to a process (in this case, gnuplot). This process won't throw any result until the pipe is closed (which occurs when the main program finishes). For example, if you try `pclose(gnuplotPipe)`, and then `getchar()`, you won't get anything until you input any character. If you really need more control over gnuplot, I would recommend to download [gnuplot_i](http://ndevilla.free.fr/gnuplot/). If you are interested, I can edit my answer to include info about this.

Comment: i made it:
`    fclose(temp1);
    fclose(temp2);
    for (i=0; i < NUM_COMMANDS; i++)
    {
    fprintf(gnuplotPipe, "%s \n", commandsForGnuplot[i]); //Send commands to gnuplot one by one.
    }
    fflush(gnuplotPipe);´

Comment: great, I added your comment to my answer for future references.

Answer (score -2):

I think you can use the multiplot command

```
set multiplot
plot data1.temp
plot data2.temp
unset multiplot
```